# Cocoa friendly URLs

Tags: cocoa, url, nstableview

I have a plus and minus button below a list in my cocoa application. Pressing the plus button opens up a file chooser dialog, and selecting a file/folder and pressing OK in it will add the URL returned by the file dialog to the list. This method works nicely, but is not very user friendly. For example, if I choose a folder inside my home directory, I get a URL like this:
`file://localhost/Users/tristan/fighterjets` Instead of those 'ugly' URLs, which I store in a hidden field in the NSTableView, could I get something more user friendly, like `/Users/tristan/fighterjets`?

Or, if possible, even something like in the Time Machine preferences where you can choose what files to exclude - the file path with the icon. I suppose this will probably require med a second column before the path and get the icon from the system in some way. I'd love to know that one too.

Comment: It's important to realise that what you consider more user-friendly is not a URL at all, but a *path* which is easily obtained with `-[NSURL path]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't show the path at all. That's not considered user friendly...  First of all, depending on the language environment the user has in the System Preferences, the file name might not be what's displayed in Finder. For example, Terminal.app becomes ターミナル.app in Japanese. You should always use [`-[NSFileManager displayNameAtPath:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CJBJDAHH).

Sorting of files by file names should be done using [`-[NSString localizedStandardCompare:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW88).

The icon associated to a file can be obtained via [`-[NSWorkspace iconForFile:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you show the path to a geek, or in a geeky UI like that of the Time Machine so that you can assume the user know what `~/` means, use

```
NSURL*fileURL= ... you get a file:// URL somehow ...
NSString* path=[fileURL path]; // extract the file system path
NSString* abbreviatedPath=[path stringByAbbreviatingWithTildeInPath]; // this converts /User/user to ~
```

for more, see [this reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAbbreviatingWithTildeInPath).

In fact, Cocoa has a pre-built UI element for showing the path called [`NSPathControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPathControl_class/Reference/Reference.html), which looks like [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGControls/XHIGControls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-SW2). So I would recommend you to use that.

Comment: The only issue I have when I add a column in front of the path with the icon is when I save the list to a file (which is required.) Apparently, you can't write an NSImage to an NSDictionary. How would I go about somehow saving the list, even with this image in it?

Comment: I would just save the full file URL or the full path without saving the image. The image and the shown string can be regenerated at each time. You see, you don't have to save everything... you only need to save the essential info, needed to re-create things.

Comment: I'll see how I can implement that. When loading the array from the plist, I could create a new NSMutableArray and add the new NSMutableDictionary objects into it, re-creating the icon there. But then I have the issue of how to get the NSMutableDictionary to not save the image part of the array... it's confusing me. Maybe I can figure it out after I had a cup of coffee and some cookies =P EDIT: I got it working, thanks very much for your solution and inspiration ;)